# Open Multiple Modals on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, inappbrowser

I have a modal in iOS React Native. Inside this modal, there is an in-app browser link. If I open the in-app browser without closing the modal, strange behavior occurs because it is not possible to have two modals open simultaneously. What is the solution? I want the modal to remain open when users open the in-app browser, and when I close the in-app browser, the modal should still be visible.

Comment: On iOS, you can't present more than one modal simultaneously or stack multiple modals shown on top of each other: https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal/issues/30.
what you can do is play with some css build your own component (the first modal) using absolute view which has the inapp browser link and open the modal with it.
So now there is only one modal open.

Comment: @Adnansayed so what you are saying is that i should change the first modal to view and modify the css to behave like modal and add the link inside it ?

Comment: Exactly, the thing is you cant open two modals at once but we can try with a view and a modal

Comment: is it even possible to make a view act like a modal? Because my modal is only covering half of the screen.

Comment: have a parent view cover the entire screen with absolute view and opacity have a chid view at the bottom of your parent view.
have a state variable boolean to toggle your parent view.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with this, [#1](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal#i-cant-show-multiple-modals-one-after-another), [#2](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal/issues/30) in **react-native**, strangely, in android works well, but this issue happens in iOS.

I solved it by:

- Using **setTimeout** for the 2nd modal after closing the 1st modal
- **Rendering conditionally** the 2nd modal in order to mount or unmount only when it is necessary.

```js
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, Text, View } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [isFirstModalVisible, setIsFirstModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [isSecondModalVisible, setIsSecondModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const onSecondModalOpened = useCallback(() => {
    // closes the first modal
    setIsFirstModalVisible(false);
    // open the second modal
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        setIsSecondModalVisible(true);
      },
      100 // animation duration, but, any small number will work
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title="Open first modal"
        onPress={() => setIsFirstModalVisible(true)}
      />

      <Modal visible={isFirstModalVisible}>
        <Text>Modal 1 content</Text>
        <Button title="Open second modal" onPress={onSecondModalOpened} />
      </Modal>
      {isSecondModalVisible ? (
        <Modal visible={isSecondModalVisible}>
          <Text>Modal 2 content</Text>
          <Button
            title="Close second modal"
            onPress={() => setIsSecondModalVisible(false)}
          />
        </Modal>
      ) : undefined}
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[Code sandbox here!](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/multiple-modal-ios-h7259t?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A1%2C1)